# Web API 2, token authentication and authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, authorization, access-token

My Web API 2 service with token authentication works always even then if I set a group where my user is not in. How can I set a role based authorization, please?

```
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"))
        {
            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");

                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "NotValidGroup")); 
        context.Validated(identity);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    **[Authorize]**
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string p)
    {
        return Ok(GetData(p));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing it into the token is right, you just need to add them to the Authorize attribute.

Your endpoint will look like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ValidGroup")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string p)
{
    return Ok(GetData(p));
}
```

If you don't specify the roles you want to have access to that resource (can be more than one, just separate them with commas) everyone who is authenticated will have access, after you specify the roles that you want to have access to that specific endpoint, only the users with those roles will be able to hit that endpoint.

You can do this at a Controller level too, just use the `[Authorize(Roles = "ValidGroup")]` before the controller.